# SQL using sysdate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have updated the value of the `SAD_PB_CAS_STATDT` field equal to sysdate which is the date today. The problem now is when i query something with that `SAD_PB_CAS_STATDT = sysdate`, it does not return anything.

see my sql code below:

```
SELECT EMPLID, ACAD_CAREER, STDNT_CAR_NBR, ADM_APPL_NBR, APPL_PROG_NBR, 
SAD_PB_CAS_STATUS, SAD_PB_CAS_STATDT
FROM PS_SAD_PB_CAS
WHERE SAD_PB_CAS_STATUS IN ('ASG', 'USD') 
AND SAD_PB_CAS_STATDT = sysdate;
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the return type of `sysdate`? does it return something with date and time? any help would be appreciated for me to be able to pull the query with `sysdate` in the conditions.

Comment: Isnt that sysdate will return current date with time. Did you try casting both sides( SAD_PB_CAS_STATDT = sysdate) to date and then check

Comment: Yep, sysdate returns both date and time. This could have been easily verified in the online mysql documentation

Comment: check [date-and-time-functions](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-sysdate-function.php)

Comment: @Praneet

how do you cast both SAD_PB_CAS_STATDT and sysdate ?

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, always check the documentation (including Stack Overflow) before you post a question.  There are several ways to make your query work, but I would recommend the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    SAD_PB_CAS_STATUS IN ('ASG', 'USD') AND
    SAD_PB_CAS_STATDT >= CURDATE() AND               -- today at midnight
    SAD_PB_CAS_STATDT < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;  -- tomorrow at midnight
```

The reason why this approach is favored over casting your `SAD_PB_CAS_STADT` column to a date only, is that the above allows an index to be used on the column, if it exists.